# Calling different JQuery function with same CSS class name

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using html.ActionLink helper to create my HTML in MVC 2.0 application. There are many ActionLink button like for example: Cancel, Submit and refresh on the same page. All these three buttons use the same CSS Class Name.
I have to call different JQuery functions (to perform differnet kind of validations) when each of these buttons are clicked. I dont have control over the CSS class. What would be the best way to acheive the result?

Comment: Is there anything different about the ActionLinks other than the URI?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML codes for those buttons you're referring to?

Comment: Do you need to support older browsers (IE6)?

Answer (score -1):

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('.vanish').fadeout('slow'); 
    });
});`

$('.vanish') is calling the css class .vanish try using something like this hopefully it helps